# Jetpack portfolio project wordpress filter

Tags: php, wordpress, portfolio, jetpack

i would like to set filters on my portfolio page. I am using jetpack portfolio project.  I am now learning php so the codex link in this question [Portfolio filter in Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21699013/portfolio-filter-in-wordpress) is very confusing to me.

Can someone help me with what i can do to get a project types filter on the page?

thanks a lot!

Comment: Can anybody help with this? Please let me know if the question is unclear. I used a menu item for the different project types but i am noticing that when a project type is selected comes up in the post format of the archives page rather than the look of the portfolio page. any help will be great. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use single-jetpack-portfolio.php as the post template for individual projects and archive-jetpack-portfolio.php for the portfolio listing page. Just use the standard loop to get the listings up on each one.